# Passing arguments to mdwlist environments

Tags: lists, environments

I'm trying to make a `description` list more compact.  I figured the easiest way to do this would be to use `mdwlist`'s description* environment.  This reduces the spacing between list items.  I'd also like to reduce the left margin to 0pt.  From the Compacted List section of the `mdwlist` documentation:

> Some list environments accept arguments. You can pass an argument to a list
>   environment using an optional argument to its compact variant. For example,
>   `\begin{foolist*}[{someargument}]`

So, I should be able to do something like `\begin{description*}[leftmargin=0pt]`, no?  Unfortunately, that returns

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing `\item`.

So, that's obviously not going to work.  Can this be done using the `mdwlist` package?  Or, am I left recreating the `description*` environment with just a small change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can better switch to `enumitem` that is more flexible in options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}[nosep,leftmargin=0pt]   %% this is local setting
    \item[Some item] This is description of the first item. Just some text to fill in the first line and go to the second line.
    \item[Some item] This is description of the first item. Just some text to fill in the first line and go to the second line.
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `nosep` makes all `sep`arations zero so that you get a compact list. These settings can be made global with `setlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description,1]{nosep,leftmargin=0pt}   %% This is global affecting all description environments at level 1
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}%[nosep,leftmargin=0pt]
    \item[Some item] This is description of the first item. Just some text to fill in the first line and go to the second line.
    \item[Some item] This is description of the first item. Just some text to fill in the first line and go to the second line.
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome.  That looks to be everything I was looking for.